# how to code multi-dimensional array in a function prototype in c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, prototype

When I create a multidimensional array like value[][],and pass it to the function.But I am quite confused about how to write a prototype for this function,because there is an error message like:

```
   error: declaration of 'value' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first|


   //function prototype;
  void matrix(double s[],int j,int n,double value[][],double alpha[], double beta[], double gamma[]);
  //function
   void matrix(double s[],int j,int n,double value[][],double alpha[], double beta[],double gamma[]){...}
```

help,How to write it correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing 2D array to function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-2d-array-to-function), [also check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/4810668#4810668)

Comment: The error is fairly obvious. You have to provide values for all dimensions except the first one in a method signature.

Comment: ty,but wut if i don't know the exact number for the second dimension?say,int k;int j; double value[k][j]; and i need to pass this two dimensional array to an function and j is given by expert which i dunno in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message from the compiler is very telling. The argument `double value[][]` needs to be changed to `double vale[][N]` where N is a integer. Examples:

```
double value[][20] // A matrix in which each row has 20 columns.
double value[][10] // A matrix in which each row has 10 columns.
```

Comment: ty,but wut if i don't know the exact number for the second dimension?say,int k;int j; double value[k][j]; and i need to pass this two dimensional array to an function and j is a variable which could be given by expert and i dunno in advance.

Comment: @user3570984 if the user is passing in the values like that, you might as well just use `double **value` instead

Answer (score 1):

the compiler already told you
error: declaration of 'value' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first|

you need specify the length, eg: double s[3], double[3][3] etc.

Answer (score 0):

The folks above have given the technical explanation.

The reason behind is is that C and C++ treat arrays as blocks of memory. When an array gets passed to a function, all that gets sent is a pointer to the array. This is in stark contrast to Ada, Pascal, and Fortran that send descriptors of the array to the function.

Your declaration must provide enough information to work with the array with just a pointer passed. That means is need all but the last (first specified) array dimension.

Multidimensional arrays of variable size are usually a sign of bad design. If you have a fixed array size (4x4 is common in 3D transforms), 2D array work out well. For something like general purpose matrix operations, 2D arrays do not work well.

For that you need to define a class that:
1) Manages a 1D array 
2) Provides the mechanism for translating 2D references into 1D index.

What you would do is something like

```
class Matrix 
{
  unsigned int range1 ;
  unsigned int range2
  double *values ; // Could use a template

  double &valueAt (unsigned int x, unsigned int y) { return values [range1 * x + y] ; }
} ;
```

Comment: ty,but wut if i don't know the exact number for the second dimension?say,int k;int j; double value[k][j]; and i need to pass this two dimensional array to an function and j is a variable which could be given by expert and i dunno in advance.So,in this case, how can i write this function array parameter?

Comment: You can't really do what you're asking for direct.

Comment: can i write a function template to indicate an arbitrary number for the second parameter ?

Comment: Yes sir.I got the solution as follows,and that works!                              template <size_t N>
void compare(string name, double value[][N]){

}